# Trick Joseki? Shoulder hit after keima to 3-4-stone

Tags: go, joseki, joseki-deviation

In a game I played, the following "Joseki" occurred:

I played the low keima against the 3-4-point, and Black responded with a shoulder hit. This move is not in the book by Takao Shinji.

In the game I attached under the 3-4 stone and created a living corner group, but Black's influence was tremendous. What should White do in this situation:

```
$$B
$$ ---------------------
$$ |..................|
$$ |..................|
$$ |..............1...|
$$ |..................|
$$ |...............2..|
$$ |..............3...|
$$ |..................|
$$ |..................|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Black's pincer is too close to White's stone (it should be at least one space lower). (This variation is not in the joseki books because it is not joseki.) That means that White can "lean on it while indirectly attacking Black's corner stone.

White should play Q15,Black plays p15, White cuts with P14, threatening to make a ladder to capture stone 3, Black extends from this stone, White ataris with P16, and quashes the corner stone with P17.

```
$$B
$$ ---------------------
$$ |..................|
$$ |..................|
$$ |..............1...|
$$ |.............8....|
$$ |.............542..|
$$ |.............637..|
$$ |..................|
$$ |..................|
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Kogo's Joseki Dictionary](http://senseis.xmp.net/?KogosJosekiDictionary). It has several variations for this move - too many to show them here.

Comment: Links to two or three of the common variations would be much more useful than a link to the KJD main page.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens There are two main variations. You can take a look online at http://eidogo.com/ if you don't want to download full dictionary in sgf format.